# Framer/Coffescript Conditional not working as expected

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

Following a Framer workshop example verbatim and for some reason cannot get a conditional statement to work.

This code runs as expected

```
layerA = new Layer
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
    borderRadius: 4
    width: 200
    height: 200
    rotation: 0


layerA.center()

layerA.states.add
  grow:
    scale: 1.5
    rotation: 90

shrink:
    scale: 1
    rotation: 0

layerA.states.animationOptions =
  curve: "spring(400, 50, 30)"

layerA.onClick ->
    layerA.states.next("grow", "shrink")
```

However, if I add the conditional below it is ignored?

```
    if layerA.states.current is "grow"
        layerA.states.animationOptions = 
        curve: "ease"
        time: 2
    else 
        layerA.states.animationOptions =
        curve: "spring(400,50,30)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the Framer API has been updated and now the `.name` property must be appended to `states.current` for this to work.

So the following conditional

```
if layerA.states.current is "grow"
    layerA.states.animationOptions = 
    curve: "ease"
    time: 2
else 
    layerA.states.animationOptions =
    curve: "spring(400,50,30)"
```

... would become

```
if layerA.states.current.name is "grow"
    layerA.states.animationOptions = 
    curve: "ease"
    time: 2
else 
    layerA.states.animationOptions =
    curve: "spring(400,50,30)"
```

Comment: You can read more about the changes in the animation API here: https://github.com/koenbok/Framer/wiki/Animation-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: @Niels: This will be excellent reference for the future, thank you.